AWS Cognito .NET Core How to Authorize User with httpOnly Flag cookie
I am sending the user an access_token that is saved in a httpOnly flag cookie. I have to override the Authorize attribute but I do not know how.
[ExtendObjectType(Name = "Mutation")]
public class MutationVeranstaltung
{
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<Veranstaltung> CreateVeranstaltungAwsCognito(VeranstaltungCreateInput input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In CreateVeranstaltungAWSCognito");
        
        return new Veranstaltung();
    }
}

